# Purpose of the Schmitt trigger in this midi circuit

Tags: raspberry-pi, schmitt-trigger, midi

I came across an [instructable](https://www.instructables.com/PiMiDi-A-Raspberry-Pi-Midi-Box-or-How-I-Learned-to/) about using midi with a raspberry pi and I was a bit confused about the first circuit from step 2. What are those Schmitt triggers for and are they really necessary?

[image: Circuit]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/FIY/H4QN/IE4ZWGRG/FIYH4QNIE4ZWGRG.LARGE.jpg))</sub>
.

According to [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/310899/midi-out-thru-circuit-questions), they are meant as a buffer for when microcontrollers couldn't sink 5mA. Seems logical but according to [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3209/what-are-the-min-max-voltage-current-values-the-gpio-pins-can-handle), the raspberry pi should be able to handle up to 16mA per pin (with some configuration).

So does this circuit really need that buffer?

Comment: Search what a Schmitt trigger is supposed to do. It has some hysteresis to filter out false pulses.

Comment: But you can also change the optocoupler that already has in-built schmitt trigger: http://www.vishay.com/docs/84896/voh1016ab.pdf

Comment: @MarkoBuršič right but why would we expect false pulses from the tx pin of the raspberry pi? I'd expect relatively clean signals from it.

Comment: That circuit is also not designed according to MIDI specification, the grounding is missing from MIDI output connector pin 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that they're Schmitt triggers is largely irrelevant. Putting two of them in series like that is doing two things for you:

- It's converting the logic levels from the 3.3 V of the RPi to the 5.0 V that the MIDI interface requires.
- It's isolating the RPi from any bad things (ESD) that might come in via the MIDI connector.

Comment: Yes, and Rpi output is 3V3 only and can't be connected up to 5V required to cut off opto current, so it could get damaged if it were connected without buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you do it putting two Schmitt trigger inverters after each other. So in principle it does not change the signal (twice inverting a signal is no change).

However, assume a signal is 1.0 V. An inverter changes the voltage under 2.0 V to 5.0V and above 2.0 V to 0.0 V. Than the signal will convert from 1.0 V to 5.0 V. And the second converter will change the signal from 5.0 V to 0.0 V. Which means the original 1.0 V (still a 'LOW' signal) is now turned into a 0.0 V, still a LOW signal but a 'better' LOW signal. So all signals will be converted from below 2.0 V to exactly 0.0 V and from above 2.0 V to exactly 5.0 V. The signals are much more clean (and can 'deteriorate' further because of possibly long MIDI cables).